# jQuery Mobile: reference to element gets lost after pagecreate

Tags: jquery, mobile

In my app, I create quite some elements using Javascript. For example, my starting HTML is something like:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="page" id="splash">
  <div data-role="content" id="splashContent">        
  </div>
</div>
```

And then in Javascript it goes like this

```
myObject.prototype.addHeader = function(headerText) {
  var splashPageContent = jQuery('#splashContent');
  this.header = jQuery('<h1>'+headerText+'</h1>');

  splashPageContent.append(this.header);
}
```

Until now, everything goes well. Problems start to arise when I want to change the header text, after the page has been created by JQM

```
myObject.prototype.changeHeader = function(headerText) {
  this.header.html(headerText);
}
```

This does not work. When I console.log 'this.header', I do get an element, but this element seems to be floating around in DOM hyperspace (e.g. it has no parents). When I select the visible header on the page (using Firebug), I get a different element than shown by console.log.

How can this be? Does JQM make clones of the header? And how can I change the text of the cloned header?

Comment: You're issuing `splashPage.append()` instead of `splashPageContent.append()`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks, no that was I typo I just fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by creating the elements *after* the pagecreate event.